# 2011 toyota tundras loses power under load

Tags: engine, toyota, power, tundra

My 2011 Toyota tundra loses power while under load it doesn't completely shut off but does not respond when pressing gas pedel. This is an occasional thing not constant

Comment: Does the amount of fuel in the tank has to do with it doing it? Example: Truck has half a tank of fuel it and never does it. It has a quarter tank of fuel and might do it.

Comment: If it has an external (outside the fuel tank) fuel filter, replace it.